# TFS build powershell script step : Not able to access $(Date:yyyyMMdd) variable

Tags: powershell, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I had created auto deployment steps using `TFS vNext` build system.
In one step I needs to access `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)` for some file versioning stuff.

Below you can find configuration and error snippet:

[image: Configuration for power shell script step]

[image: Error while queuing build]

So any idea how to access date related variables as argument in PowerShell script step ?

Comment: Hi, do you expect the to have current date in `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)` ? You could use `$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd)`.

Comment: I need to pass it as param from Build PowerShellScript step, is it gonna work ?

Answer (score 8):

"$(Date:yyyyMMdd)" is a [token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general#tokens) for Build number format, not a [variable](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general#variables). So you cannot use it in the build steps.

The alternative way to do this is to set the "Build number format" under "General" tab to "$(Date:yyyyMMdd)", the variable "$(Build.BuildNumber)" will be filled with the value of "$(Date:yyyyMMdd)". And then you can use "$(Build.BuildNumber)" variable in the build steps.

Comment: This clue helped, i had create one extra step to modify a custom variable which will set to (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMddHHss') and pass that variable in consecutive steps.

Comment: Today in VTST, "General Tab" doesn't exist, the correct tab is "Options", and then, edit the "Build number format" input text field.

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, `date` is not a function. You could set the `-fileName` parameter in your `CompressFile` script to:

```
Param(
    [string]$fileName = 'Package{0}' -f (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
)
```

And omit the parameter in the TFS VNext argument list (you can still overwrite it).

Comment: Make sense but i can't use it in this way, as this file is shared across multiple projects packaging and every single one of them have different prefix.

Comment: Then omit the date postfix when you invoke the script and append it within the `CompressFile` script...